# Elementary graph theory representation

Tags: graph-theory

We've been talking about graphs in class and my understanding is that $K_3$ means a graph $K$ has $3$ nodes. I have also been reading online to get a better understanding of what was said in class but then I came across multiple examples and blog posts talking about $K_{3,3}$

So my question is, what does $K_{3,3}$ mean? is it simply saying $6$ nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$K_3$ refers not just to any graph with 3 nodes (vertices), but rather to the complete graph on 3 vertices. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) for more information about complete graphs.

Meanwhile, $K_{3,3}$ refers to something called a bipartite graph. This is a graph for which the vertices can be separated into two sets, such that all of the edges cross from one set to to the other. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteBipartiteGraph.html) for a precise definition and more information about bipartite graphs.